# Want Answer to match with randomly generated question

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a quiz and I have randomly generated a question from a pool of 15. The correct answer is in a separate list but they all match up i.e. Answer[0] is the correct answer for Question[0].

```
Random random = new Random();
lblQuestion.Text = Questions[random.Next(0, Questions.Count - 1)];

btnCorrect.Text = Answers[];
btnIncorrect1.Text = Answers[random.Next(0, Answers.Count - 1)];
btnIncorrect2.Text = Answers[random.Next(0, Answers.Count - 1)];
btnIncorrect3.Text = Answers[random.Next(0, Answers.Count - 1)];
```

I tried creating an int "a" and having it equal to lblQuestion.Text.Count but this always outputs "2".

Answer (score 1):

Just store your random integer and use it for the answer also:

```cs
Random random = new Random();
int questionNumber = random.Next(0, Questions.Count - 1);
lblQuestion.Text = Questions[questionNumber];
btnCorrect.Text = Answers[questionNumber];
```

A more traditional way to implement it would be to create a class that holds both question and answer, put them all in an array and then shuffle that array by the generic Random.Shuffle method. Now you can use the first item as the question and correct answer and the next three as wrong answers.

The problem with your current approach is that you put the correct answer back in the pool and make it available as wrong answer. You avoid that by shuffling and using specific indices.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me

 lblQuestion.Text = Questions[random.Next(0, Questions.Count - 1)];
            int questionNumber = random.Next(0, Questions.Count - 1);

            btnCorrect.Text = Answers[questionNumber];
            btnIncorrect1.Text = Answers[random.Next(0, Answers.Count - 1)];
            btnIncorrect2.Text = Answers[random.Next(0, Answers.Count - 1)];
            btnIncorrect3.Text = Answers[random.Next(0, Answers.Count - 1)];

Still giving me the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0)?
You could refactor your questions/answers to be stored in a dictionary, the questions being the key and the answer being the value to find the answer relating to your question more efficiently.

```
Dictionary <string,string> content = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

Overall I think creating a struct might suit your problem better:

```
private struct qAndA
{
    public qAndA(int number, string question, string answer)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public readonly int number;
    public readonly string question;
    public readonly string answer;
}
Random random = new Random();
List<qAndA> listContent = new List<qAndA>();
listContent.Add(new qAndA(1,"Capital of France?", "Paris"));
listContent.Add(new qAndA(2,"Capital of Australia?", "Canberra"));
listContent.Add(new qAndA(3,"Capital of Canada?", "Ottawa"));
listContent.Add(new qAndA(4,"Capital of Germany?", "Berlin"));
    
qAndA chosen = listContent[random.Next(listContent.Count)];
```

The chosen qAndA object will always have its answer linked to its question. You can iterate through your created list to assign randomly an answer to each button(And add something to not select the same qAndA to 2+ buttons).

Comment: Would that allow the questions to appear in random order? That is one of the requirements?

Comment: @JCunningham struct being more appropriate for your issue (I think), I edited my answer above to give you an example.